# .htaccess - Run PHP file before authentication

Tags: php, .htaccess, basic-authentication, .htpasswd

I'd like to generate a password for authentication with .htaccess with PHP dynamically. The PHP file contains the algorithm to generate the password and writes this password into a .htpasswd file.
So: Is it possible to let the .htaccess file run this script when the directory is browsed before the authentication box is displayed (so the password is generated instantly before authentication)?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You can [let PHP handle authentication](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) and then you are free to verify passwords any way you want.

Comment: Okay, that's pity. Thank you. Then the PHP authentication seems to be the only way for my desires.